# Symfony2 Lose authentication when go back to public area

Tags: security, symfony, firewall, provider

I have implemented a `security.yml` file for my website. It uses two differents providers used for two differents login form.
When I am authenticated on a authentified area and I go to the public area (anonymous area), I lose my identification informations and I get a "You are not authenticated." in the debug bar.

The site map is something like this:

- Home, Faq... (Anonymous)
- Professional/Manager (Auth with professional_security provider)
- User (Auth with customer_security provider)

  ```
  security:
   encoders:
     Project\SiteBundle\Entity\User: 
         algorithm:        sha512
         encode_as_base64: true
         iterations:       1            
     Project\SiteBundle\Entity\Professional: 
         algorithm:        sha512
         encode_as_base64: true
         iterations:       1
  providers:
    customer_security:
      entity: 
        class: Project\SiteBundle\Entity\User
        property: login
    professional_security:
      entity: 
        class: Project\SiteBundle\Entity\Professional
        property: login 

  firewalls:
      dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: true
        anonymous: ~

      Public_area:
       pattern: ^/
       anonymous: ~

      Professional:
        pattern: ^/professional/.*
        anonymous: ~
        provider: professional_security
        form_login:
            login_path: /professional/login
            check_path: /professional/login_check
            success_handler: authentication_handler
        logout:
            path: /professional/logout
            target: /professional/login
        security: true

      Customer:
        pattern: ^/user/.*
        provider: customer_security
        form_login:
          login_path: /user/login
          check_path: /user/login_check
          success_handler: authentication_handler
        logout:
          path: /user/logout
          target: /user/login
        security: true

   access_control:
    - { path: ^/professional/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/user/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/user/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/professional/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTIFICATED_FULLY}
    - { path: ^/professional/beautician/.*, roles: ROLE_BEAUTICIAN}
    - { path: ^/professional/manager/.*, roles: ROLE_MANAGER}
    - { path: /user/.*, roles: ROLE_CUSTOMER}
    - { path: ^/faq, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
  ```